# Post event from fragment to its activity's parent activity

Tags: android, otto

Need help with https://github.com/square/otto.

In my application I have

`ActivityBase` with :

```
 @Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    SmartApplication.bus.register(this);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onResume();
    SmartApplication.bus.unregister(this);
}
```

`ActivityOperationBase extends ActivityBase` with :

```
@Subscribe
public void onNextStepRequest(NextStepRequestEvent event) {
    //...
}
```

`ActivityMobile extends ActivityOperationBase` with `FragmentCommonEnterMoney` in it. This fragment has button which does

`SmartApplication.bus.post(new NextStepRequestEvent(/*params*/));`

on it's click. But it doesn't fire

```
 @Subscribe
 public void onNextStepRequest(NextStepRequestEvent event) {
     //...
 }
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Please post a bit more code

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are creating new `NextStepRequestEvent`, and not calling `onNextStepRequest`.

Actually you want to use `onNextStepRequest` from fragment, to do this create interface

```
public interface OnNextStepRequestCallback{
  public void onNextStepCallback(NextStepRequestEvent event);
}
```

and use it

```
public class ActivityMobile extends ActivityOperationBase implement OnNextStepRequestCallback {

    public void onNextStepCallback(NextStepRequestEvent event){
       onNextStepRequest(event);
    }   
}
```

To call above method pass `OnNextStepRequestCallback`'s reference to `FragmentCommonEnterMoney` from `ActivityMobile` like (or override Fragment's `onAttach`)

```
FragmentCommonEnterMoney  frag = new FragmentCommonEnterMoney();
frag.setOnNextStepRequestCallback(this);
```

inside your `FragmentCommonEnterMoney` use

```
public class FragmentCommonEnterMoney  extends Fragment{
private OnNextStepRequestCallback eventCallback;

    public void setOnNextStepRequestCallback(OnNextStepRequestCallback callback) {
         eventCallback = callback;
    }
}
```

and use `eventCallback` to trigger `onNextStepRequest` from your fragment

Comment: Yes... but I use Otto library

Comment: Doesn't matter, this code will be in your project's activity file